# Create all-in-one bundle?

Tags: stenciljs

I'd like to know if it's possible to create an `all-in-one.js` bundle, which includes all components, so it wouldn't be necessary to load other script tags.

My config:

```
exports.config = {
  srcDir: "./webcomponents",
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: "dist",
      dir: "./build/webcomponents/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box this isn't available. This is intentional, to provide zero-config code-splitting and other performance benefits. [Here's a GitHub issue with a bit more detail](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/683).

That said, as of 0.9.0 Stencil now produces an `esm/` folder, which you can bundle yourself into an all-in-one bundle using Webpack or Rollup.

Comment: Btw, I've tried, and it works (at least after calling `myapp.defineCustomElements(window);`), but the styles don't show on Firefox, because it generates the styles like `:host{cursor:pointer}` instead of `[data-my-component]{cursor:pointer}`, even thought I built `es5`. Any idea?

Comment: Figured out why: I wasn't using the `*.sc.js` files ("sc" means "scoped").

Comment: @kraftwer1 If you really managed to completely circumvent the lazy-loading and bundling _everything_ into one file, would you care to share your solution?

Comment: @ChristianUlbrich Unfortunately - I haven't been successful. And I don't even think it's possible without touching the code of Stencil.js itself. Because for each component, Stencil.js generates two components: one for browsers with native support, and one that is polyfilled.

Comment: @ChristianUlbrich just a crazy thought that I wouldn't do myself: Maybe you could write an offline file server as a web worker.

Comment: @kraftwer1 do you have a, example in github on how you achieven packing everything?

Comment: @MichelTobon I did not - at least not completely (styles not showing...). This has to be built within Stencil.js.

Comment: @matthewsteele, where is it mentioned that esm/ directories can be bundled up into one js ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create a bundle of individual stencil components by using webpack with the plugin [@stencil/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stencil/webpack).

Just add the plugin, then in your entry file, import `your/stencil/component/file.js`

Comment: And that works with scoped styles as well? Meaning it runs on IE11 with styles?